# Angular application cannot find files in sub directory

Tags: angular, typescript, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to deploy Angular application in Apache sub directory. I added this .htaccess configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /admin/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I used this command to compile the code:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /admin/
```

But when I open one page I get this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): e: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found","url":"http://185.185.185.185/admin/api/transaction_notes/unique_id/219","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://185.185.185.185/admin/api/transaction_notes/unique_id/219: 404 Not Found","error":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL /admin/api/transaction_notes/unique_id/219 was not found on this server.</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 185.185.126.15 Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n"}
```

Can you give me some advice how I can solve this isssue?

Comment: Here is the file: https://pastebin.com/zYqdPVgs

Comment: Which line, Can you paste the entire config as answer please?

Comment: I tested it but it's not working.

Comment: I would remove one line after another to see which one causes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error looks like it is related to your API call using a relative URL, but not to the app loading itself. If that is the only issue you could fix that in a simple way by putting a slash in front of your url:

```
this.http.get('/api/transaction_notes')
```

instead of `this.http.get('api/transaction_notes')`

For anything else you might have to provide more information and code.